# Why aren't pivot_longer() and pivot_wider() perfectly symmetric?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Running the following script

```
library(tidyverse)
stocks <- tibble(
  year   = c(2015, 2015, 2016, 2016),
  half  = c(   1,    2,     1,    2),
  return = c(1.88, 0.59, 0.92, 0.17)
)
stocks %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = return) %>% 
  pivot_longer(`2015`:`2016`, names_to = "year", values_to = "return")
```

would give the following result

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
   half year  return
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 2015    1.88
2     1 2016    0.92
3     2 2015    0.59
4     2 2016    0.17
```

Why aren't pivot_longer() and pivot_wider() perfectly symmetric?

Comment: Do you mean the column order?

Comment: They are symmetric in the sense that you have the same data values with the same column names, but the column and row order are shifted. I think that by definition reshaping data is an information-destroying process, in that information like column order is made irrelevant when you pivot longer, for instance. So the resulting order is a design choice that might not match your original order. If the row order is important, that should be encoded with a row number column, and if the column order is important then the column names should include that. If you do that the order will be retrievable.

Comment: `pivot_longer` is sorting on `half`. As to "why" - because that's the design decision the developers made? You can always add `%>% arrange(year)` to restore the original ordering.

Comment: Please note that unless the data is a time series, or even panel/longitudinal data, row and column arrangement have no impact on the data. Similar data upto column/row permutation are considered to be equivalent. This is the main bhavior of `SQL`. and its repeated across all data analysis/science. So in your case, the two results are equivalent, hence the two functions are symmetric.  Note that equivalence is different from identical.